# Do the Struts2 interceptors implement Chain of Responsibility?

Tags: design-patterns, struts2

Can I say that the [Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/) Interceptors could be the typical example for [Chain of responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx)?

The servlet dispatcher send request and a banch of interceptors process the request on the way to the action. The request can go through all the interceptor or at some point it will break the chain.

Comment: interceptors are more of cross cutting concern but in some sense they fit in to chain of responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. To me, the "Chain of responsability" pattern implies a hierarchy of candidate handlers, such that one of them either handles (and "consumes") the object/command OR delegates it to the "superior". By contrast, the chain of struts2 interceptors are not hierarchical (order might matter, but that's all), and typically each interceptor does something (more akin to a "decoration" or an "observation" than to a "handling") with the request AND passes it to the following interceptor. One does not say that "the interceptor X has handled the request", the real handler is the struts2 Action.

Conceptually,  Struts2 interceptors are very similar to the **filters** in the [2.3 Servlets API](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2001/jw-0622-filters.html). And I don't think that filters fit in the "Chain of responsability" pattern, either.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it depends on your definition.

It is a chain of responsibility in the sense that each interceptor can view the request and its eventual handler, modifying either, and short-circuit or modify request processing.

It's not in the sense that an interceptor isn't the intended destination of a request--actions are (which implement the command pattern).

I'd say Struts 1.3 fits a more-conventional definition of CoR, but it's more an issue of terminology. S1.3 commands still revolve around prepping requests--it's a flexible implementation of the old monolithic request processor.

So yes and no. Or maybe.